# 3D-Coordinate Transformation in C#

Tags: c#, math, multidimensional-array, 3d, trigonometry

**What is the Goal?:**
I want to know the new Coordinates of a point after rotating the 3D-Object (Cuboid), around the anchorpoint (x,y & z) on the opposite side.

**What i did:**
I tried to calculate the position with the following function. I had to convert `doubles` to `floats` , because of the Autodesk Inventor API. Note: `Vector` is the difference from the `origin` /anchorpoint to the designated point.

```
Vector3 coordinateTransformation(Vector3 vector, float r_x, float r_y, float r_z, Vector3 origin)
        {
            vector.X = vector.X;  //Just for demonstration
            vector.Y = vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_x))) - vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_x)));
            vector.Z = vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_x))) + vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_x)));
            
            vector.X = vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_y))) + vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_y)));
            vector.Y = vector.Y;  //Just for demonstration
            vector.Z = vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_y))) - vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_y)));
            
            vector.X = vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_z))) - vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_z)));
            vector.Y = vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_z))) + vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_z)));
            vector.Z = vector.Z;  //Just for demonstration

            vector.X = Math.Abs(vector.X) + origin.X;
            vector.Y = Math.Abs(vector.Y) + origin.Y;
            vector.Z = Math.Abs(vector.Z) + origin.Z;
            
            return vector;
        }
```

Somehow the object does not get placed on the correct place.

**Next step:** On the internet i found a website which does the correct transformation.[Casio Website](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/15362817755710)
If i manually set `vector` to the calculated point on the website, everything else works fine. **So i somehow have to get the exact same calculation into my code.**

If you need further information, feel free to comment!

**Edit:**
**1 :** I want to place 2 Objects (e.g. Cuboids) within 1 Assembly Group in Inventor. Every Object as an anchorpoint (origin) and on the opposite side a connection point, which is described as the delta between the anchorpoint and the connection point itself. At first one Object is placed on the origin coordinates, followed by a rotation around the anchorpoint (degrees). After that the connection point coordinates of Object 1 have changed. In the next step i want to place Object 2 with its origin on the connection point of Object 1, while Object 2 has the same rotation as Object 1.
**2 :** Inventor uses a right-handed coordinate system

Comment: Can you give an example of one point, the rotation angles, and the expected results?  Also, `r_x`, `r_y` and `r_z` are not very descriptive because rotation sequence matters and it is not specified here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply rotation to a vector manually, you'd need to **update all the components (X, Y and Z) at once** as follows.

```
Vector3 coordinateTransformation(Vector3 vector, float r_x, float r_y, float r_z, Vector3 origin)
{

    // In the rotation around X axis below, `Y relies on Z` and `Z relies on Y`. So both must be updated simultaneously. 
    vector = new Vector3(
        vector.X,
        vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_x))) - vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_x))),
        vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_x))) + vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_x)))
    );

    vector = new Vector3(
        vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_y))) + vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_y))),
        vector.Y,
        vector.Z * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_y))) - vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_y)))
    );

    vector = new Vector3(
        vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_z))) - vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_z))),
        vector.X * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(r_z))) + vector.Y * Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(r_z))),
        vector.Z
    );

    vector.X = Math.Abs(vector.X) + origin.X;
    vector.Y = Math.Abs(vector.Y) + origin.Y;
    vector.Z = Math.Abs(vector.Z) + origin.Z;

    return vector;
}
```

### Appendix: Use of Matrix4x4

As @JonasH suggests, it's a good idea to use reliable libraries, if there are.

Since, row-vectors are used in the .NET world (while your implementation is based on column-vectors), `X->Y->Z` rotations can be written by straightforward matrices multiplications as follows.

```
Vector3 coordinateTransformation(Vector3 vector, float r_x, float r_y, float r_z, Vector3 origin)
{

    var mat = Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX(DegreesToRadians(r_x))
        * Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY(DegreesToRadians(r_y))
        * Matrix4x4.CreateRotationZ(DegreesToRadians(r_z));

    vector = Vector3.Transform(vector, mat);
    
    vector.X = Math.Abs(vector.X) + origin.X;
    vector.Y = Math.Abs(vector.Y) + origin.Y;
    vector.Z = Math.Abs(vector.Z) + origin.Z;

    return vector;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I made it! Also thanks for the advice with the 'update at once'!

Answer (score 1):

Do not mess around with vectors and angled by hand. Use some library for your vector functions and use matrices to do your transformations. For example [System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.quaternion.createfromyawpitchroll?view=net-7.0) or Math.Net.Numerics.

Assuming you have an euler angle to start with you can use [CreateFromYawPitchRoll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4.createfromyawpitchroll?view=net-7.0) to create your rotation matrix. If you want to rotate around a specific point you just subtract your rotation center from all your points, apply the rotation and move the points back. This can all be done by just multiplying the transformation matrices:

```
var totalTransform = Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(-rotationCenter) *
                    Matrix4x4.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(yawInRadians, pitchInRadians, rollInRadians) *
                    Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(rotationCenter);
```

to apply the resulting transform you just call [Vector3.Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3.transform?view=net-7.0) to produce a new, transformed vector.

This will all be a bit easier if you have some introduction to linear algebra. It is also common to do things like applying the transforms in the wrong order or something, and sometimes it is easiest to just try some different things until you get it right. I would also note that rotations are just hard to understand. I tend to prefer quaternions over eutler angles, not because the math is easier to understand, but since there are methods like [CreateFromAxisAngle](https://Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle), that I *can* understand.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much! Unfortunately i dont get it to work properly. 
`Vector3 coordinateTransformation(Vector3 rotationCenter, Vector3 connectionPoint, float yawInRadians, float pitchInRadians, float rollInRadians)
        {
   var totalTransform = Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(-rotationCenter) * Matrix4x4.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(yawInRadians, pitchInRadians, rollInRadians) * Matrix4x4.CreateTranslation(rotationCenter);
   Vector3 test = Vector3.Transform(connectionPoint, totalTransform);
   Console.WriteLine(test);
   return test;
        }
` This doesnt return correct values. :/

Comment: @JohnStep Are you sure you got the angles correct? Euler angles are kind of a pain since there are at least 12 different ones, and  you have to use the same one as `CreateFromYawPitchRoll`. Also note that some methods assume a right handed coordinate system, if you use a different convention you will not get the values you expect.

Comment: I tried just rotating around the x-Axis, so i converted 60 degrees it into radians and put it into the `rollInRadians` attribute. Any suggestions, of what i did wrong ? :) I also edited the question, if you need further information. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnStep If you are just rotating around the X axis, just use Matrix4x4.CreateFromAxis with the x-axis as the axis argument instead. That way you do not have to guess what 'roll' corresponds to.

Comment: Yeah that was just for the test, in the end there will be 3 angles given. I will try that anyways!